# How to count all descendants of a parent category in sql using recursive

Tags: sql, postgresql, prisma

I am using prisma for my database schema.
Schema on Prisma:

```
model Category {
  id                Int              @id @default(autoincrement())
  name              String
  parent_crawler_id Int?
  url_slug          String?
  createdAt         DateTime         @default(now())
  updatedAt         DateTime         @updatedAt
  item_categories   ItemCategories[]
  crawler_id        Int              @unique @default(1)
  orderIndex        Int?
  path              String?
  Item              Item[]
}

model ItemCategories {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  item_id     Int
  item        Item     @relation(fields: [item_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  category_id Int
  category    Category @relation(fields: [category_id], references: [id])
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

Category has 2 categories namely Veg and Fruit.
Veg category has a crawler_id of 1 and Fruit has crawler_id of 2. Fruit has a 1 child namely Organic with an id of 10. Organic has a parent_crawler_id of 2. Organic has 1 child namely Apple. Apple has parent_crawler_id of 10 and has id of 11. In the ItemCategories table the attached category_id is 10 and 11.

How do we count the total descendants of Fruit and Veg category that are attached to the items in ItemCategories table using the recursive method in sql?

e.g
ItemCategories table

```
id      category_id     item_id
1       10              1
2       11              2
```

Comment: You can use https://dbfiddle.uk/btGcOH30 to create a reproducible example. Update you post with an URL and the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should answer your updated question:

```
WITH RECURSIVE category_tree AS (
  SELECT 
    c1.id,
    c1.name,
    c1.parent_crawler_id,
    c1.crawler_id
  FROM Category c1
  WHERE c1.crawler_id IN (1, 2) -- Veg (crawler_id: 1) and Fruit (crawler_id: 2)

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    c2.id,
    c2.name,
    c2.parent_crawler_id,
    c2.crawler_id
  FROM Category c2
  JOIN category_tree ct ON c2.parent_crawler_id = ct.id
)

SELECT
  ct.crawler_id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT ic.item_id) AS total_descendants
FROM category_tree ct
JOIN ItemCategories ic ON ic.category_id = ct.id
GROUP BY ct.crawler_id;
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question, what I mean is that to count all categories that have items in the ItemCategories table.

Comment: Thanks
I just need to change the line  JOIN category_tree ct ON c2.parent_crawler_id = ct.crawler_id instead of ct.crawler_id I used ct.id

Comment: Thanks @Jearson, sorry was a little tired :) feel free to accept this answer so that it can help others